# multiply two text field and automatically update third one in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

How to multiply two text field float values and automatically update it in the third one in iphone?

I am getting warning: local declaration of 'distance' hides instance variables
$

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    double distance = [self.distance.text doubleValue];
    double mileage = [self.mileagerate.text doubleValue];
     amount.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",distance * mileage];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is because you have a text field named distance an a local variable also named distance.  Rename your local variable and the warning should go away:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    double dist = [self.distance.text doubleValue];
    double mileage = [self.mileagerate.text doubleValue];
     amount.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",dist * mileage];
}
```

Comment: But this is not working properly. At times, the amount doesn't show anything.

Comment: It sounds like (at least) one of your text fields isn't populated when this method is called.  Also, if either of the text fields doesn't contain a value that can be parsed to a double, the conversion, and therefore the calculation, will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You have an instance variable called `distance`. And you also define a local variable called `distance` in that method. That's why you get the warning.

I recommend you rename your text fields. It's usually better to actually name them what they are. I would call them `distanceTextField` or `distanceField` and `mileageRateField`.

Answer (score 1):

**About warning -**

```
self.distance //Global Variable
double distance //local variable
```

both variables has same name thats why you're getting warning otherwise your method is okay.

You can calculate it on `return button` just change your variable name for remove warning...

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
     double distance_local = [self.distance.text doubleValue];
     double mileage = [self.mileagerate.text doubleValue];
     double result = distance_local * mileage;
     amount.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",result];
     [textField resignFirstResponder]; 
     return YES;
}
```

You can also calculate it in

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Method but in every method you have to check that both `textFields` has value of not.